# Time Validation Range form MySQL

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

This is my JavaScript:

```
<SCRIPT TYPE="text/JavaScript">
    function validateHhMm(inputField) {
        var time= $("#time").val();
        var isValid = /^(time)?$/.test(inputField.value);

        if (isValid) {
            inputField.style.backgroundColor = '#bfa';
        } else {
            inputField.style.backgroundColor = '#fba';
        }

        return isValid;
    }
</SCRIPT>
```

PHP Script:

```
 <?php
            include 'connect.php';
            $time = " SELECT * from schedule where id_ship=24";
            $show_time = mysql_query($time);
            $row = mysql_fetch_array($show_time);
    ?>

    <input type="text" onchange="validateHhMm(this);"  name="time" id="time" value="
      <?php 
        echo $row['time_coming'];
      ?>">
```

this schedule table

```
id_ship     |  time_coming |
----------------------------
24          |  11:10:02    |
```

I want to input form time again. And valid value must same or above 11:10:02. Invalid value under 11:10:02.
So, what should I do in my JavaScript?

Comment: It's not really clear to understand what you want. Could you elaborate a bit?

Answer (score 0):

You're going to want to validate the time on both the server and client end.

Let's change the JavaScript function so that it can accept a minimum value.

```
<SCRIPT TYPE="text/JavaScript">
    function validateHhMm(inputField, minValue) {
        var time= $("#time").val();
        var isValid = /^(time)?$/.test(inputField.value);

        if (!isValid || inputField.value < minValue) {
            inputField.style.backgroundColor = '#fba';
        } else {
            inputField.style.backgroundColor = '#bfa';
        }

        return isValid;
    }
</SCRIPT>
```

So, if the inputField.value doesn't validate your regex, or isn't a time smaller than the minimum, it's deemed invalid.

Now, pass the minimum to the JavaScript, using:

```
<input type="text" onchange="validateHhMm(this,<?php echo $row['time_coming'];?>);"  name="time" id="time" value="
      <?php 
        echo $row['time_coming'];
      ?>">
```

Okay, now that JavaScript is validated, you need to validate over PHP as well.

You didn't post any code for the POST page, but the validation will look something similar to:

```
if ($_POST['time'] < $your_row['time_coming'])
    die("Invalid time posted")
```

Answer (score 0):

Given that you have:

```
<input type="text" onchange="validateHhMm(this);"  ... >
```

then you are passing a reference to the element to the function, so in the function:

```
var time= $("#time").val();
```

is identical to:

```
var time = inputField.value;
```

Where you have:

```
var isValid = /^(time)?$/.test(inputField.value);
```

you are testing the value of *inputField* to the literal string "time", which will almost certainly be false. If you wish to test that the time is a valid time, (i.e. hours are 0 to 23 and minutes are 0 to 59) you might try:

```
function validateHHMM(s) {
  var b = s.split(':');
  return /^\d\d:\d\d$/.test(s) &&   // Check format is nn:nn
         b[0] < 24 && b[0] > -1 &&  // Check hours are 0 to 23 inclusive
         b[1] < 60 && b[1] > -1     // Check minutes are 0 to 59 inclusive
}
```

The above can be done in a single regular expression, but simplicity matters when someone else has to maintain the code.

Once the input is valid, you can then compare the values.